# Remmina scaling options

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remmina, scaling

What is the purpose of the following settings in Remmina and how to use them?

1. Desktop scale factor %
2. Device scale factor %

[image]

I'm connecting Ubuntu 18.04 to Windows 7 through RDP and interested in scaling Windows 7 Desktop. Everything is too small at 2560x1440 on my hi-resolution Linux laptop monitor. I've tried to start RDP session in lower resolution and scale to full screen and it seems blurry.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this merge request](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/merge_requests/979) on the Remmina Gitlab page:

> Desktop Scale Factor: scaling of desktop and desktop apps, range from
>   100% to 500%
>
> Device Scale Factor: scaling of metro (appstore?) apps. Works on
>   Win2012R2, windows 10 seems to ignore it. Can only be 100%, 140% or
>   180%.